# cakephp: Warning (2): mysql_connect()

Tags: cakephp

Using cakephp: I create a website & after upload my site to main server when I browse index page of my website it shows me
**cakephp: Warning (2): mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql**

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the connection settings within /app/config/database.php?